# Passing std::unique_ptr as qt signal argument with std::move

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, qmetaobject

I'm working in Qt, I didn't mention it, because I thought it was just C++ problem.

I solved this problem with shared pointers, so don't give me solution. But it's question of comprehending, I want to understand why it's not working.

I was trying the following:

test.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include "response.h"
#include <memory>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void signal(std::unique_ptr<Response> resp);

public slots:

};
```

test.cpp:

```
Test::Test(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Response> response(new Response(5));

    emit signal(std::move(response));
}
```

`Response` class:

```
class Response
{
public:
    Response(int data);

private:
     int data;
};
```

I know that `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied and I use `std::move` here. But in spite of this I get an error:

```
moc_test.cpp:75:85: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Response; _Dp = std::default_delete<Response>]’
         case 0: _t->signal((*reinterpret_cast< std::unique_ptr<Response>(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
```

In the following snippet of `moc_test.cpp`, which is product of Qt meta-object system:

```
void Test::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void `_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        auto *_t = static_cast<Test *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
//------- !! This line!!
        case 0: _t->signal((*reinterpret_cast< std::unique_ptr<Response>(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        default: ;
        }
    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod) {
        int *result = reinterpret_cast<int *>(_a[0]);
        {
            using _t = void (Test::*)(std::unique_ptr<Response> );
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(_a[1]) == static_cast<_t>(&Test::signal)) {
                *result = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Spent much time, but I couldn't figure it out why that error occurred and didn't find anything helpful in the internet.

Comment: Do you really need to use pointers here (unique or otherwise)? If it turns out you don't need it then that would, indirectly, also solve your problem.

Comment: Please post a [mre], without blanks to fill. We need to be able to reproduce it reliably.

Comment: Post the full error message, it is not clear which line generates that.

Comment: The currently posted code compiles and works fine. You're doing a copy somewhere else: https://godbolt.org/z/5eCtsb

Comment: After trying to make example, I found out that code in previous post was working. So I added to post more information and reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Creating Custom Qt Types](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/custom-types.html)* mentions the constraints imposed on a Qt meta-type, i.e the type requires a copy constructor (to be emit-able).

The reason that **`const`** is mentioned in the error message is that we're trying to invoke the (deleted) copy constructor of the `unique_ptr` (as indicated by the message).

I suspect that while the move is taking place when passed as parameter, you're still assigning the rvalue (e.g in the constructor).

***Note***, you haven't posted all the code, but my suspicion is that your code fails for the same reason as the code below:

```
#include <memory>


struct Foo {
    std::unique_ptr<int> pointer_;

    explicit Foo(std::unique_ptr<int> pointer) : pointer_(pointer) {
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> pointer(new int(10));
    Foo{move(pointer)};


    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

**The failure being:**

```
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo(std::unique_ptr<int>)’:
prog.cpp:8:63: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
  explicit Foo(std::unique_ptr<int> pointer) : pointer_(pointer)
```

The reason is that copy initialization is taking place (of **`pointer_`**). You need to call `move` to move the (now lvalue **`pointer`**) into the member.

I would suggest the code perform the initialization to be modified as follows:

```
struct Foo {
  std::unique_ptr<int> pointer_;

  explicit Foo(std::unique_ptr<int>&& pointer) 
  : pointer_(move(pointer)) { //**NOTE** the move here!!!
  }
};
```

Note that I did not pass `std::unique_ptr` by value. In practice it would always be an rvalue, and perhaps the additional move constructor call would be elided (I'm not sure, but I just use an rvalue reference in these circumstances).

Also note that it is not necessary to qualify `move`, as it will looked up as result of [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Added copy constructor, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: No, the solution is not to add a copy constructor (you can't modify unique_ptr...). The solution is to use a type that doesn't have a deleted copy constructor (as is the case with unique_ptr). You can't use unique_ptr, because it doesn't have a copy constructor. You're solution of using shared_ptr is right, because it has a copy constructor

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant! And I thought about copy constructor of class which is unique_ptr pointed to! Now it's more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Qt signal delivery depends on being able to copy the arguments.  A signal can be connected to many slots, so it doesn't make sense to pass a unique pointer; all but one of the recipients would get a null.

You'll need to convert it to shared pointer or change your approach.

Comment: Agree, will consider it. In my case it's one to one connection.

Comment: Correct me, if I'm not right in my approach. I need to send object, but it's not good approach (as I think) to make another copy of object, when I can send just a pointer. As object is in local scope, I create it dynamically. Is there better solution?

Comment: Without the context, I can't know, but it seems reasonable to convert to shared pointer for the signal.  Qt doesn't know or care how many slots your signal will be connected to.